# Converting a nested type into a monad transformer stack

Tags: haskell, nested, monads, monad-transformers

I’m having some trouble with one of the exercises in the Monad Transformers chapter from [*Haskell Programming From First Principles*](http://haskellbook.com/). Specifically, we are given a structure that looks like `(const (Right (Just 1)))` and are asked to finish the following:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

embedded :: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int
embedded = ??? (const (Right (Just 1)))
```

I assume this means that we cannot change the nested structure, although the instructions are only to "make it work."

I've gone through a few routes before concluding that I am stuck. So far, from what I gather, monad transformers are most commonly created with a combination of `lift`s and `do`s — aside from the SO Q&As, [Diehl summarizes pretty well here](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/001_basics.html#monad-transformers).

I've also been working with the `map<Monad>T` variants from the `transformers` library to get some interesting / fun results, but I can't seem to find out how to solve the original problem. Any hints would be appreciated — however, if you post a solution, [please use the spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup) (although I've never seen it used on anywhere other than in Puzzling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exercise really shows how monad transformers can sometimes work "inside out". Start by figuring out how to wrap up that expression so you get something of type

```
ReaderT () IO (Either String (Maybe Int))
```

Then figure out how to get `MaybeT`. Etc.

Don't forget that you're allowed to use the `ReaderT`, `EitherT`, and `MaybeT` data constructors!

This would be a great time to try out GHC's *typed holes* if you haven't already.

Comment: Gah — and it _was_ as simple as I thought it would be. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @stites, no problem!